# What are the machine code differences of various bool? queries?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

There are a many ways on how you can query the value of a bool?.

What are the machine code differences of them and what makes the faster than the others?

```cs
bool? test = true;

bool a = test == true;
bool b = test ?? false;
bool c = test.GetValueOrDefault();
```

I know there are longer queries with `null` checks but these three are the shortest and fastest that I know. I created some [benchmarks](https://github.com/reiseder/nullable-bool-benchmark) with longer queries too. Using these methods is preferred I'd say as they are the fastest, which is not what I'm asking for anywhere. I'm only interested in the low level machine code differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sharplab.io, we can see that `test == true` compiles to:

```
(test.GetValueOrDefault() == true) & flag.HasValue
```

Which follows from the definition of the [lifted form of the `==` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators). Since this has a call to `GetValueOrDefault` in it, it is definitely slower than `test.GetValueOrDefault()`.

On the other hand`test ?? false` actually compiles to a call to `test.GetValueOrDefault()`, so they are the same.

Although `test == true` is the slowest here, it's just some extra pushing to the stack + comparing things + ANDing things, which should not matter in the grand scheme of things. You probably wouldn't have a bottleneck *here* of all places. At the end of the day, you should use whatever that expresses your intent the most clearly.

[Sharplab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTABgLACh4EZWpgFgAQBiAFAEYD2ZEA/HsAKYDOwAlHgN6p5d4zoCcRekzwBeEbQBOAVzrMA3J268BQ4Hio0AZgEMIDWQpTce/QY2AA6AOJ1gANV0yA8hIAidHVIjAizeagBfIA==)

Comment: Didn' t know about sharplab.io. Thanks for that!